# Installed Application and dropbox download link for new install also not working : iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, dropbox

We have one dropbox link for one application which user use to download the application is not working right now.

User which were using the application everyday are now not able to open the application as gets minimized or may be crashed.

Application from Xcode is working fine.

What might be solution to above problem?

I think provisional profile might have been expired as I don't have right to enterprise account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many cases like following :

**Firstly install Application**

1. When application gets installed from any source and does not open.

   1. Application is open in background mode then provision profile is expired.
   2. Application not in background then something is wrong while installing application.

**Not able to install Application**

1. Need valid provisional profile for device.
2. Select appropriate provisional profile for device.